# Redirect in ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.Net **MVC4 Razor**. I'm having a problem with **redirection**. I wanna redirect the user to the Home controller at the user login(if login is valid). 
But my problem is it always come back to the login page even the redirect meythod also fired.

Here is my code..

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LoginAccess()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

}
```

Login page..

```
<div class="body_wraper">
<div id="cloud" style="background:url('@Url.Content("~\\Content\\cloud.png")');">
    <div id="login_form">
        <div class="Three-Dee">Login here..</div>
         <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Label("Username")</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("txtUsername")</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Label("Password")</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@Html.Password("txtPassword")</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;"><button class="k-button" id="login" onclick="Login()">Login</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Login() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Login/LoginAccess")',
        type: 'POST'
    });
}
```

Home Controller..

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session["UserName"] = "Administrator";
        string menu = this.GetMenu();
        ViewBag.ManueItems = menu;
        return View("User");
    }
```

After **click on the login button** it comes to **LoginAccess in Login controller** and then comes to **Home controller Index** method, but **doesn't view the "user view"**.
But when i check with **typing url** >>(**host__/Login/LoginAccess">http://__*host*__/Login/LoginAccess**) **Its working properly.**
Please help me to slove this problem. 
Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may misuse the Ajax function here

You should use  **@Html.ActionLink("Login", "LoginAccess", "Login")** instead

Ajax is originally used to get something from server side other than affecting currently browsing page.

Comment: Missed that. Well spotted. Yes, you can't post back a page like that  via Ajax. Ajax just sends back a "copy" and disposes of the returned page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) . I've tried this, but it doesn't worked. 
$("#login").click(function () {
        @(Html.ActionLink("Login", "LoginAccess", "Login"))
    });

Comment: @user2549153: You are misusing HTML.ActionLink... That generates an HTML anchor in the page, not javascript. Please view the source of the page you generated to see what was created.

Comment: Hey, pls learn the basic HTML before using the .NET MVC given function 

Learn **<a href="\Login\LoginAccess">Login</a>** first, then try

**@Html.ActionLink("Login", "LoginAccess", "Login")**


Basically, they are the same thing

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing `Ajax` calls, you cannot force redirect from controller. You can fix this by 2 ways:

1. Replace ajax call with regular get.
2. Return a json from the action and use redirect from javascript

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
return redirect("/Home/Index")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var result = new ControllerName().YourAction();
```